# Getting Point Cloud Data from Kinect v2 to PCL

Tags: kinect, point-cloud-library

I'm trying to link Kinect with the PCL library, and following [this](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/openni_grabber.php) tutorial, but the grabber solution that I have built just crashes, stating that abort() was called. What exactly caused the problem and is there a workaround for this?

Comment: I don't believe Kinect v2 is supported under the grabber class of PCL. You need to write your own program to get the xyz coordinates using the kinect v2 library. These coordinates can be place in an pcl point cloud.

Answer (score 1):

this is my grabber https://github.com/giacomodabisias/libfreenect2pclgrabber.
I am integrating it in pcl here:https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/pull/1410

You can find example for a single kinect2 and form multiple kinect2s in the repo.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Kinect v2.0 is supported under the grabber class of PCL. You can get it from the web.
http://download.csdn.net/detail/xx__hu/8571209